Removing /wp in Permalink URL of subdomain led to inaccessibility to WP Dashboard
I am a beginner and learning to develop a website through practicing. Basically using Elementor Plugins.

When I noticed my Home/Front Page URL https://kuluguskham.cskulung.com/wp I thought the last /wp was unnecessary.
I entered into the WP Dashboard and found at permalink URL has the same URL kuluguskham.cskulung.com/wp
I thought by mistake I added the character /wp so I deleted the characters /wp from the permalink URL and click on Save Changes.
After that I tried to visit my subdomain site i.e. https://kuluguskham.cskulung.com the message was appeared Page Not Found.
Then I tried to enter into WP Dashboard of the subdomain placing the URL https://kuluguskham.cskulung.com/wp/wp-admin it is also not working.

When I place the admin URL to enter into WP Dashboard, the URL converts as below.
https://kuluguskham.cskulung.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fkuluguskham.cskulung.com%2Fwp%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
I have no idea how to fix it.
So technical assistance is expected to overcome this issue.

is your WP install actually installed in the root folder? Or did you install it in a wp subfolder? If you check the filesystem via FTP/control panel it should reveal this. If that's the case then you can't remove the wp unless you physically move the WordPress install up 1 level then do a URL migration on the database to move it all up 1 level in the content

I have installed WP in both the main domain and subdomain. The main problem is that no WP login box appears after placing the subdomain admin URL. So I am not able to enter into Subdomain WP Dashboard.

you didn't answer my questions, ignore the URLs and look at the filesystem on the server, there's no such thing as installing WP "in a domain", WP gets installed in a folder and Nginx/Apache are told to take visits to example.com and run WordPress. If you put that WP install in a wp subfolder then your WP install will be accessible at example.com/wp, making it accessible at example.com without the wp would require moving it up 1 level in the filesystem

I entered into the main domain (cskulung.com) FTP/cPanel. The FTP Accounts shows the Directory for main domain and subdomain Directory:                              1. For main  domain  /home/cskulung: public_html/cskulung.com/CSKulung                                             2. For subdomain /home/cskulung:  public_html/kuluguskham.CSkulung.com.                         Do you think we can do something here? Please let me know.

that tells me where the webroots are but it doesn't tell me where WordPress is, is WordPress located in the webroot or in a subfolder named wp? That you've shared 3 paths suggests you have 3 separate WordPress installs

Thanks Tom for the suggestion so far given me to find out the root cause of the issue and to solve it. Now it is solved by the Web Hosting Co.
